# How to apply AlphabeticSort to a code cell?

Tags: notebooks

I've got a single code cell in a notebook with *lots* of `Usage` messages in no particular order.  I'd like to alphabetize them, but doing it manually would be a nightmare.  Is there a way to use `AlphabeticSort` to automate this task?

E.g.

```
Foo::usage="Foo does this.";
Bar::usage="Bar does that.";
Baz::usage="Baz does something else.";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this code in a cell after your usages cell. Save your notebook before you try it because it is a quick prototype:

```
NotebookWrite[PreviousCell[], #]& @
BoxData @ 
Sort[#, AlphabeticOrder[#[[1]], #2[[1]]] &][[All, 2]] & @ 
Map[ {Cases[#, RowBox[{sym_, "::", "usage"}] :> sym, Infinity][[1]], #} & ] @ 
DeleteCases[_String] @ 
NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]][[1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!